# how to improve face recognition accuracy in facenet

Tags: elasticsearch, face-recognition, face-detection, cosine-similarity

I am trying to develop a Bollywood face recognition system in videos. I have used facenet to generate training image embedding and store 128-bit face embedding in the elastic search index. recognition happens by using test face embedding being compared with elastic indexed embedding using l2 similarity measure. it seems that chances of misclassification with low similarity threshold is very high. if I increase the threshold the recognition will be poor(less). how can we improve the model in this setup. does triplet loss training come into the picture here, if so how can I do that? any help with this will be very much helpful and well appreciated. thank you

Comment: Just put the final update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience (I'm using face_tecognition/ dlib for making 128d face encodings) Elasticsearch works perfectly, even much better then instant dlib methods:

```
                s_body = {"size": app_conf.ELASTIC_MAX_RESULTS, "min_score": 1 - tolerance,
                          "query": {
                                "script_score": {
                                    "query": {
                                        "match_all": {}
                                    },
                            "script": {
                                "source": "1 / (1 + l2norm(params.query_vector, 'face_vector'))",
                                "params": {"query_vector": wanted_encoding}
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                res = es.search(index="idx", body=s_body)
...
 for hit in res["hits"]["hits"]:
    ...
```

Update from 13.02.202:
Also, as I already wrote I'm using standrd pre-trained face_recognition_model.
However, some preprocessing measures are implemented too:

- check if face is rotated:

  def face_align(img, box_index, eyes=None, checksideview=True):
  """[Rotate face to upright position]

  ```
    Args:
        img ([nparray]): [base input phoyo]
        box_index ([int]): [number of facebox is multiface]
        eyes ([list]): [coordinates of eyes ("left_eye" (x, y) - "right_eye" (x, y))]

    Returns:
        [boolean]: [True  if face is rotated too much: more then 5 fegrees]
        [nparray]: [corrected/rotated to upright position image]
    """
    reload(app_conf)

    if not eyes: # no eyes data being provided
        boxes, eyes = mp_boxes(img, fl_use_dlib=True, fl_use_mediapipe=False, fl_verbous=False)

    if eyes:
        left_eye_x = eyes[box_index][0][0] 
        left_eye_y = eyes[box_index][0][1]
        left_eye = (left_eye_x, left_eye_y)

        right_eye_x = eyes[box_index][1][0]
        right_eye_y = eyes[box_index][1][1]
        right_eye = (right_eye_x, right_eye_y)

        if checksideview: #check if face rotated tooo much
            left_chin_x = eyes[box_index][2][0]
            left_chin_y = eyes[box_index][2][1]
            left_chin = (left_chin_x, left_chin_y)

            right_chin_x = eyes[box_index][3][0]
            right_chin_y =eyes[box_index][3][1]
            right_chin = (right_chin_x, right_chin_y)

            right_dist = euclidean_distance(right_chin, right_eye)
            left_dist = euclidean_distance(left_chin, left_eye)

            k_side_face = right_dist / left_dist
            if 0.5 > k_side_face or k_side_face > 2.0: #change acorrding to exp.
                return False, img # face is "from a side" tooo much

        if left_eye_y > right_eye_y:
            point_3rd = (right_eye_x, left_eye_y)
            direction = -1 #rotate clockwise
        else:
            point_3rd = (left_eye_x, right_eye_y)
            direction = 1 #rotate counter clockwise

        a = euclidean_distance(eyes[box_index][0], point_3rd)
        b = euclidean_distance(eyes[box_index][1], point_3rd)
        c = euclidean_distance(eyes[box_index][1], eyes[box_index][0])
        cos_a = (b*b + c*c - a*a)/(2*b*c)

        angle = np.arccos(cos_a)
        angle = (angle * 180) / pi

        if angle < app_conf.MIN_FACE_ROTATION: #if rotation less then 5 degrees
            return True, img

        if direction == -1:
            angle = 90 - angle

        new_img = Image.fromarray(img, mode="RGB")
        new_img = np.array(new_img.rotate(direction * angle))
        new_img = cv2.cvtColor(new_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        return True, new_img

    else:
        return True, img #do nothing
  ```

And "eyes" I'm getting from:

```
def mp_boxes(image, confid=0.4, fl_use_dlib=True, fl_use_mediapipe=True, fl_verbous=True):
    """[Function uses Medipipe CNN to find out all faces boxes on the given image. 
     It's about 50 times faster even on CPU but sometime consupms huge amount of RAM...
    then original dlib / Face_recognition functions.]
    If Mediapipe found no face boxes (it's possible and depends of image features,
    the function consequently tries to use dlib CNN and HOG models for that.)

    Args:
        image ([np.array]): [image in memory to be proccessed]

    Returns:
        boxes [list]: [list of coordinates of face boundaries boxes]
        eyes [list]: [list of (left_eye, right_eye) for every box]
    """    
    reload(app_conf)
    mod5_68 = "large"
    boxes = []
    dboxes = []
    eyes = []
    if fl_use_dlib:
        if DLIB_USE_CUDA: #tryin to use CNN on GPU first
            try:
                dboxes = frfl(image, number_of_times_to_upsample=1, model="cnn")
                for box in dboxes: #checking MIN_FACEBOX_DIM conditions
                    if (box[1] - box[3]) > app_conf.MIN_FACEBOX_DIM[0] and (box[2] - box[0]) > app_conf.MIN_FACEBOX_DIM[1]:
                        boxes.append(box)
                if fl_verbous:
                    print("[INFO] %s: dlib CNN being used and found %dface box" % (datetime.now(), len(boxes)))
            except:
                dboxes = frfl(image, number_of_times_to_upsample=1, model="hog")
                for box in dboxes:
                    if (box[1] - box[3]) > app_conf.MIN_FACEBOX_DIM[0] and (box[2] - box[0]) > app_conf.MIN_FACEBOX_DIM[1]:
                        boxes.append(box)
                if fl_verbous:
                    print("[INFO] %s: dlib HOG being used and found %d face box" % (datetime.now(), len(boxes)))
        else:
                dboxes = frfl(image, number_of_times_to_upsample=1, model="hog")
                for box in dboxes:
                    if (box[1] - box[3]) > app_conf.MIN_FACEBOX_DIM[0] and (box[2] - box[0]) > app_conf.MIN_FACEBOX_DIM[1]:
                        boxes.append(box)
                if fl_verbous:
                    print("[INFO] %s: dlib HOG being used and found %d face box" % (datetime.now(), len(boxes)))
    
    del(dboxes)
    
    if fl_use_mediapipe:
        face_detection = mp_face_detection.FaceDetection(min_detection_confidence=confid)
        iheigth, iwidth = image.shape[:2]
        results = face_detection.process(image)
        if results.detections:
    # further with  results.detections:
            for d in results.detections:
                xmin = int(iwidth * d.location_data.relative_bounding_box.xmin)
                ymin = int(iheigth * d.location_data.relative_bounding_box.ymin)
                ymax = ymin + int(iheigth * d.location_data.relative_bounding_box.height)
                xmax = xmin + int(iwidth * d.location_data.relative_bounding_box.width)
                if (xmax - xmin) > app_conf.MIN_FACEBOX_DIM[0] and (ymax - ymin) > app_conf.MIN_FACEBOX_DIM[1]:
                    boxes.append([ymin, xmax, ymax, xmin])
        else:
            if fl_verbous:
                    print("[INFO] %s: Mediapipe found nothing :(" % datetime.now())
        
        del(face_detection)
        del(results)

    if boxes:
        for box in boxes:
            basic_landmarks = frfland(image, [box], mod5_68)
            eyes.append((basic_landmarks[0]["left_eye"][2],
                         basic_landmarks[0]["right_eye"][1],
                         basic_landmarks[0]["chin"][16],
                         basic_landmarks[0]["chin"][0]))
        if fl_verbous:
            print("[INFO] %s: Mediapipe addded some too and now totally %d face boxes are collected." % (datetime.now(), len(boxes)))
        return boxes, eyes
    else:
        return None, None
```

Where

```
frfland = face_recognition.face_landmarks()
mp_face_detection = mediaoioe.solutions.face_detection
```

2. Minimal facebox is 30 x 30 pixel
3. Maximum picture size is 1280 x 1024 (using cv2.resize). Such reduction is criticaly important for the case of CUDA picture processing: my NVODIA with 4 GB onboard can't work with bigger files.
4. I'm using both dlib and Mediapipe face box detection: sometimes it is useful :)

Comment: Ya i am using the same pattern for query. But there will be misclassification sometimes.in my case similarity threshold 0.09 gives good match but in some cases it will be a misclassification.  Beyond 0.12 threshold there will be very less matches. However my dataset face images may be limited. My struggle here is to understand does any further techniques can be used to make this better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm operating with aprox. 10 million faces and it takes 5 sec (kn my hardware) to find out top 20 the best with 0.3 (!) threshold. 100% identical faces (in fact) normally have 77-80% or more (i.e. <0.23) similarity on Elasticsearch's opinion.

Comment: Thats great ! Thanks for the response. Do you use any kind of specific criteria for training images. I meant to say quality attributes of face images to be considered such as face angle,  pixel quality wise.  Also i  have included preprocessing steps for training images which have enough height and width (resolution wise) and pixel quality.  Further At this stage i suspect whether including more training example may solve the issue or not.  In my case i use this for face recognition so i consider 1 top hit with highest similarity to give label for face matched.

Comment: Let me answer by adding some the the answer above.